# Is there a need to make a connection string to a database in the same PHP file if the conection is to the same database?

Tags: php, database, connection

Is there any need to make a connection string to a database like that

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , NULL , 'books');
```

and to set the charset every time after the connection string like that:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con , 'utf8');
```

in the same PHP file every time we want to execute a query?

Comment: Not unless you disconnect after every query.... once a connection has been made, it's available for the duration of the request

Answer (score 0):

ideally you'd only want to create the connection once and reuse the same connection resource on subsequent queries to the database.
so on any given "page" or "file" you'd create the connection then set your char set then just reuse that connection foe the rest of the queries on that "page" or "File"